# React Native, Dimensions.get('window') cant be passed as parameter to a child component and make it work inside styled components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styled-components

i got this annoying *issue which i can not solve.
Any help appreciated!

So on React Native in a parent component Im getting the screen dimensions (which im using for react-native-snap-carousel) with :

```
const { width: screenWidth } = Dimensions.get('window');
```

Im trying to pass this screenWidth as a parameter to a child component that renders the exact component passed in the carousel also.

The code looks like this:

```
{bankDetailsLoaded && banksDetails?.length > 1 ? (
        <Carousel
          sliderWidth={screenWidth}
          useScrollView={true}
          itemWidth={isTablet() ? Theme.util.wp('60%') : Theme.util.wp('85%')}
          data={banksDetails}
          shouldOptimizeUpdates={true}
          renderItem={renderBankItem}
        />
      ) : bankDetailsLoaded && banksDetails?.length > 0 ? (
        <BankAccountInfoCard
          item={banksDetails[0]}
          screenWidth={screenWidth}
          accountNumber={accountNumber}
          shareHandler={shareHandler}
          copyToClipboardHandlerItem={copyToClipboardHandlerItem}
          shareSwiftHandler={shareSwiftHandler}
          isUK={isUK}
        />
      ) : null}
```

The BankAccountInfoCard is the child component, but in that component when i try to use screenWidth in styled components as:

```
width: ${({ screenWidth }) => `${screenWidth}px`};
```

or:

```
width: ${(props) => props.screenWidth}px;
```

or even:

```
width: ${Dimensions.get('window').width}px;
```

i get errors with all those approaches.

Comment: Why are you passing a function to `width`? Can't you just write `width: screenWidth`?

Comment: @Kipnoedels No cause then i get this error  {JSON value 'screenWidth' of type NSString cannot be converted to a YGValue. Did you forget the % or pt suffix?}

Comment: Don't cast screenWidth to a string. Either use numbers, or string when using '%'

Comment: No i made it actually by passing as props in the component i wanted the screenWidth and then used it in styled componetns. Thank you for your info